# Upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu Desktop from 20.04 → 22.04. Does anybody is experiencing something similar or knows how to solve this issue

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1873, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 906, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 99, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 122, in jammyPostInitialUpdate
    self._test_and_fail_on_pam_tally()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 395, in _test_and_fail_on_pam_tally
    content = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 16: invalid start byte
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1873, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 906, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 99, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 122, in jammyPostInitialUpdate
    self._test_and_fail_on_pam_tally()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 395, in _test_and_fail_on_pam_tally
    content = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 16: invalid start byte
```

Comment: First impression: Seems like your file `/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-wuemd46g/jammy` is corrupt (unreadable). Delete that file and start over.

Comment: Thank you. I tried deleting it. But unfortunately, it keeps failing with the same error.